# Capturar OnClickListener de un RecyclerView en Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Normalmente al armar un adaptador para `RecyclerView` en la detección de clicquear sobre un elemento lo computo desde el `ViewHolder`.

Creo que sería mucho mejor si se puede interceptar el `OnClickListener` del RecyclerView desde el `Activity` similar al antiguo `ListView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando por SO en varias soluciones he conseguido delegar el `OnClickListener` del `RecyclerView` al `MainActivity` esos son los pasos

**Integrar una interface al Adapter**

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
```

**Declarar el ClickListener**

```
public class PackagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    ...
    private static ClickListener clickListener;
}
```

**Definir setOnItemClickListener**

```
public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    PackagesAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}
```

**En el ViewHolder Asignar el onClick**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView mTitle;
    TextView mSummary;
    ImageView mAvatar;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mSummary = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        mAvatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }

}
```

**Interceptar el OnClick al Activity**

Se recibe la posición donde se ha pulsado

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick position: " + position);
    }
});
```

**Extra: obtener datos del adapter**

Si no se tiene la fuente de datos y se quiere obtener el que hay en el adaptador

En el adaptador definir

```
public Tipo_de_dato getItem(int position) {
    return (listData != null) ? listData.get(position) : null;
}
```

en el MainActivity.java

```
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
        Tipo_de_dato item = mAdapter.getItem(position) ;
    }
});
```

**Extra: Capturar OnLongClickListener**

Se debe declarar en la interface

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
}
```

En el ViewHolder capturar el OnLongClickListener y asignarlo a su listener

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
    TextView mTitle;
    TextView mSummary;
    ImageView mAvatar;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this); 
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        return true;
    }
```

En el MainActivity

```
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            //Capturar OnClick
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position, View v) {
            //Capturar OnLongClick
        }
    });
```

Comment: alguna ventaja/desventaja de tener el onclicklistener dentro de onBindViewHolder en lugar de en ViewHolder?

Comment: La ventaja para mi es que puedes separar más el código de funcionalidad con lo de visual, además de poder reatulizar el adaptador por otros fines, por ejemplo dos listas pero al hacer click en una abra un activity y la otra pues muestre un dialogo

Comment: Hola @Webserveis . Copié el código del onclick y me  sale el error de que no se puede hacer en un objeto con referencia nula :( . Podrías darme una mano?